# iOS - Chromecast - app not loading media

Tags: ios, chromecast

I have a problem with launching media from iOS app. When I call `mediaControlChannel loadMedia:`, nothing happens on receiver app - no loading bar appears, but neither of `GCKMediaControlChannelDelegate` methods are being called. After waiting some time, when I disconnect from the device, only then delegate receives `didFailToLoadMediaWithError` with error 92: unexpected disconnect.

I thought that the media or some of the parameters are incorrect, so I used them in Google's example iOS app, but it all works fine there.

Before trying to load media I check if I'm connected to device and to the application, mediaControlChannel is added to deviceManager. I also call `requestStatus` on mediaControlChannel to make sure I don't get `kGCKInvalidRequestID` and everything's fine. Only then I try to load media, but as I said - it just doesn't work, no error, no feedback from receiver app. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Have you compared your code with the CastVideos-ios sample project?

Comment: Yes, I have, I couldn't find anything wrong with my code.

Comment: Any follow-up or resolution on this? I am currently in the exact same position. I did find that using the default application ID kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID for the receiver worked, but that breaks the remote display channel part of our application.